# Can I make each NUnit test run on a separate process?

Tags: nunit

Can I force each nunit test method to run on a separate process ?
I need to do this because calling some of the methods-under-test may have side-effects. So, I need to make sure that each unit test run in complete isolation from the other unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the  "/process" option to specify - single or separate or multiple options. Here is the reference to the NUnit documentation for version 2.5: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.5. Look at the Controlling the Use of Processes section.